# Azure Function Trigger for List<POCO> Storage Queue

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

We have a subscription to Event Grid with an endpoint type as Storage Queue (say xyz-queue). We also have an Azure Function which is a Queue (xyz-queue) trigger. Every message in xyz-queue storage Queue is EventGridEvent object. I have Azure Function trigger something like below:

```
public static void Run([QueueTrigger(xyz-queue, Connection = "connnection")] EventGridEvent ege)
```

Since, there will be 1000's of messages with same POCO object (in this case EventGridEvent), is there a way where we can read multiple messages, process them together and also ensure we are not reading more than 5 messages so that function do not take long time to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of queue messages that the Functions runtime retrieves simultaneously and **processes in parallel**. When the number being processed gets down to the `newBatchThreshold`, the runtime gets another batch and starts processing those messages. So the maximum number of concurrent messages being processed per function is `batchSize` plus `newBatchThreshold`. This limit applies separately to each queue-triggered function.

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "queues": {
            "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
            "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
            "batchSize": 5,
            "maxDequeueCount": 5,
            "newBatchThreshold": 2
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings).

Also, if you want to output queue message multiple with poco, you could use [`ICollector` and `IAsyncCollector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/queue-storage#using-icollector-with-azure-storage-queue-bindings).

Comment: So by default the batch size is 16. is it like each function instance can read max 1 message from the queue at a time? So there will be 16 function instances processing 16 messages from queue concurrently in a VM?

Comment: No. You can process 16 message in parallel in one instance.